# in python, how to replace featurespace module with pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below code, how to do it using pandas or any other?

```
from FeatureSpace import FeatureSpace
fs.load('ps_mf_gt_frm_hana',
     filepath='bouns_files',
     files='abc.csv',
     append=False,
     delimiter=',',
     encoding='utf8',
     fillna=False,
     data_types={'val_usd':'str', 
                 'quantity':'str',
                 'cost_usd':'str',
                 'fiscl_date':'date'
                }
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ps_mf_gt_frm_hana = pd.read_csv( 'bouns_files/abc.csv', delimiter=',', encoding='utf8' )
```

First, read the data frame in pandas dataframe variable with the name ps_mf_gt_frm_hana and then perform the operations like fillna(), column datatypes, etc.
You can use fillna API, astype API from pandas for the same respectively.
For example,

```
ps_mf_gt_frm_hana ['val_usd'] = ps_mf_gt_frm_hana ['val_usd'].astype(str)
ps_mf_gt_frm_hana ['quantity'] = ps_mf_gt_frm_hana ['quantity'].astype(str)
ps_mf_gt_frm_hana ['cost_usd'] = ps_mf_gt_frm_hana ['cost_usd'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, much appreciated.

is there any alternate for fs.summary() in pandas or any other module?

Comment: You can try ps_mf_gt_frm_hana.describe() If you want to see first few rows try, ps_mf_gt_frm_hana.head()

Comment: Also do consider marking it as resolved if you find the answer helpful