# How to rewrite the code by removing FeatureSpace in python

Tags: python-3.x

how to rewrite the code by removing FeatureSpace in python by using pandas or any other module?

```
from FeatureSpace import FeatureSpace

fs.aggregate('map_mat_to_prd_group_and_division',
         file_name_ps_hana,
         index_vars=['material'],
         agg_vars=['PRODUCT_GROUP','PRODUCT_GROUP_TXT', 'division'],
         agg_functions=['last'],
         agg_var_names=['PRODUCT_GROUP','PRODUCT_GROUP_TXT', 'division'])
```

Comment: What is FeatureSpace?

Comment: FeatureSpace is module/library, my intention is how to achieve above logic without using FeatureSpace?

Comment: I understand that it is a library. What does it do? What "logic" are you talking about?

Comment: mapping from material to product group / division

Comment: And what does "mapping from material to product group / division" mean? You have not explained what the "logic" is. You have not explained what FeatureSpace actually is used for.

Comment: This question looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/66433542/407651